# Verificar tamanho de unidade de rede mapeada

Tags: delphi-7, batch, cmd

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo, e preciso verificar o espaço livre
na unidade de rede mapeada, consigo pegar o conteúdo de um arquivo
no diretorio da minha aplicação, então criei um script para executar o comando
para verificar o espaço livre em `batch`:

```
unidade  := 'Z:';
caminho  := ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName);
vCommand := 'fsutil volume diskfree '+unidade+' | find /i "livres disp" > '+caminho+'\unidade.txt';
WinExec(PChar('cmd /c "'+vCommand+'" '),SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Com o código acima, e trocando a unidade para `c:`, tenho o retorno esperado, mas quando troco para `Z:`, não funciona.

Ou se teria outra forma de fazer isso, estou utilizando [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim

```
var
  FreeAvailable,TotalSpace,TotalFree : Int64;
begin
  GetDiskFreeSpaceEx('z:',FreeAvailable,TotalSpace,@TotalFree);
  ShowMessage('Espaço livre: '+FormatFloat('#,0',TotalFree));
end;
```

Fonte: http://www.planetadelphi.com.br/dica/1128/-obtendo-o-espaco-livre-em-disco.

Comment: Retorna 0, mas se coloco `c:`, retorna o valor. Já havia tentado vlw

Comment: @David estranho, testei aqui em uma rede mapeada e mostrou o tamanho.

Comment: Testei em um novo projeto, e teve retorno, deve alguma coisa no meu projeto :/

Comment: é provável, tem que ir "garimpando" agora